# audio clip bounds not remaining fixed when clip is moved

Tags: audio, imovie

I had a clip which I detached the audio from.  I then trimmed the audio clip, and tried to copy and paste it so I would have two identical clips of the audio one right after the other.

However, the copy doesn't sound anything like the first clip.  Instead, it appears that the audio is offset from the original clip, possibly by the exact length of the first clip.

If I try moving the clip, it appears that the bounds of the audio clip (the starting and ending point) don't remain fixed, but instead acts as if the audio clip is fixed to the timeline and moving the clip is just exposing a different part of the clip.  But the first thing I did was detach the audio.

How do I make the clip behave properly so I can paste it to multiple locations?

I am running iMovie version 10.1.14 on Mac OS X 10.14.6.

Comment: Software you’re using?  macOS version?

Comment: @Allan I have updated the question with this info

Comment: Any relevant screenshots would also be helpful